# Limitar tamanho de um item em flexbox

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Estou tentando fazer uma toolbar com flex, porém os ícones estão tomando toda a toolbar quando eu passo com o cursor por cima:

```css
@media screen{

    :root{
        --primary-color: #29f1c3;
    }

    *{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    img{
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }

    /*    Navgation    */
    .main-toolbar{
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 56px;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
    }

    .main-toolbar .menu-btn{
        background: none;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        display: flex;
        margin-left: 3%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .account-btn{
        background: none;
        border: none;
        outline: none;
        display: flex;
        flex: 1;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        margin-right: 3%;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

}
```

```html
<nav class="main-toolbar">

            <button class="menu-btn">
                <img class="menu-icon" width="48" height="48" src="../assets/icons/ic_hamburger.svg" alt="" />
            </button>

            <button class="account-btn">
                <img class="account-icon" width="48" height="48" src="../assets/icons/ic_account.svg" alt=""/>
            </button>
        </nav>
```

Como podem ver ao passar o mouse por cima toda a toolbar fica selecionável, como faço para apenas os botões ficarem selecionáveis?

Comment: O problema é esse `flex: 1` no seu segundo botão. Se não tiver nenhum motivo específico, remova ele e substitua o `justify-content` na sua classe `main-toolbar` para: `justify-content: space-between`. Vai continuar com a mesma aparência de agora.

Comment: @Renan parece que o problema é esse mesmo, pq vc não posta como resposta?

Comment: @hugocsl ando meio desanimado de participar. :/

Comment: @Renan te entendo bem camarada, pode acreditar! A situação está cada vez pior... Força ai 

Comment: @Renan seu comentário resolveu me problema, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

você precisa remover o **display:flex** das tags button, remover também a propriedade **flex:1** do segundo botão e para alinhar você pode usar a propriedade **justify-content**. Segue abaixo o código corrigido.
 - obs1: comentei o que precisa ser removido;
 - obs2: troquei as imagens por algumas que encontrei na web só para elas ficarem visíveis aqui.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <title>Teste</title>
    <style>
 @media screen{
  :root{
   --primary-color: #29f1c3;
  }
  
  *{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }
  
  img{
   max-width: 100%;
   height: auto;
  }
  
  /*    Navgation    */
  .main-toolbar{
   background-color: var(--primary-color);
   width: 100%;
   min-height: 56px;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center; /*flex-start | flex-end*/
  }
  
  .main-toolbar .menu-btn{
   background: none;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   /*display: flex;*/
   margin-left: 3%;
   cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .account-btn{
   background: none;
   border: none;
   outline: none;
   /*display: flex;
   flex: 1;*/
   flex-direction: row-reverse;
   margin-right: 3%;
   cursor: pointer;
  }

         }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="main-toolbar">

        <button class="menu-btn">
            <img class="menu-icon" width="48" height="48" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b2/Hamburger_icon.svg/1200px-Hamburger_icon.svg.png" alt="" />
        </button>

        <button class="account-btn">
            <img class="account-icon" width="48" height="48" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/User_icon_BLACK-01.png" alt=""/>
        </button>
    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```